# Windows 10 now displays English in some parts of non-English OS version

Tags: windows-10, user-interface, modern-ui, language-pack

I recently started noticing parts of my Windows 10 OS in English when they should be in Portuguese, as it has always been. This wasn't a big deal, but it was nagging after a while so I wanted to figure out why this was the case, it seemed to have started in early-mid February and I attributed it to some Patch Tuesday kind of thing.

As an example, here's what it looks like:

[image: Windows UI language issue]

After playing around with the latest updates, I wasn't getting any results. Although I have the OS installed from scratch using an official ISO from MediaCreationTool, natively with the Portuguese language, I still understand that the user interface builds upon MUI resources for translating the interface.

I started looking at those and I found a few different variants of the same MUI files. Some were inside `C:\Windows\System32\pt-PT`, but others were inside `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackpt-PT_19041.37.118.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Windows\System32\pt-PT`

I don't remember ever installing any *Language Experience Pack*, but anyway... I started with what was nagging me, which was those menus in the explorer ribbon. Those strings come from `explorerframe.dll` or more specifically from `explorerframe.dll.mui`.

I compared the version that came natively with the one from that LXP from WindowsApps, here's what I found:

[image: MUI comparison]

- *Left: `explorerframe.dll.mui` (2022-02-10, pushed silently by Microsoft through its Store as part of the LXP app*
- *Right: `explorerframe.dll.mui` (2019-12-07, shipped natively)*

There should be no English strings given that both the OS and the language pack aren't English and were properly translated before February. Somehow Microsoft built the latest language packs and at some point something went wrong and it pushed English strings into some of the non-English resources (someone also confirmed similar issues with the Swedish language).

So, what then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently, manually uninstalling the LXP app works, with the caveat that Windows will silently push the same app again the next time around, even if you disable the Store's app auto-update feature.

Here's how you get to uninstall it:

- Run elevated Powershell
- To remove Portuguese (Portugal) LXP: `Get-AppxPackage --AllUsers Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackpt-PT* | Remove-AppxPackage --AllUsers`
- To remove any/all languages LXPs: `Get-AppxPackage --AllUsers Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePack* | Remove-AppxPackage --AllUsers`
- Reboot

Again, this is only temporary seeing as Windows will silently install the faulty package once again at a later time. As of now, I do not know of any solution to prevent the forceful installation of Local/Language Experience Packs.

The "definitive fix" seems to be for Microsoft itself to fix these language packs.